# Collecting data from table

Tags: jquery, mysql, database

I have created a registration page where a user can register up to 20 other people. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/cRUsQ/2/) is what that page looks like. I am using the validate plugin to validate all my inputs.

What I am having a problem with is, if the user adds 20 entries into the table to register that many people, how do get all that data and:

1. validate it like I do to the normal text boxes?
2. get all the data and post it so I can insert it into a mysql database?

Comment: Which [server-side scripting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-side_scripting) technology are you using?

Comment: @mdmullinax Server side technology is completely irrelevant. He only asked how to validate them (from javascript) and how to post them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the array syntax on input names like so: `name="fname_new[]"`. This will generate an array of those starting with key 0 and going up to however many you have. For validation give your functions some names, use jQuery selectors to select all inputs of a type which match a validating function, and call it on each input you want to validate. As for posting the values, just post the form (eliminate all invalid rows first).

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta Okay so my inputs now look like this: `<td name="fname_new[]"><input type=text /></td>` but when I click submit, the table data doesn't get posted to the next page. Am I doing it right or did you mean something else?

Comment: I just copyedited the question, @Timothy. user1675804 wrote the answer.

Comment: Ah, @user1675804 the above question was for you then, sorry.

Comment: Some sample test code posts the data so I guess you're removing the inputs from javascript, try this without any js:
`<form method="post" action="">
<input name="test[]" type="text" value="first test box" />
<input name="test[]" type="text" value="second test box" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>`

Comment: Oh sorry, I just noticed, the names should be on the input and not elements in your code.

Comment: @xception okay, i fixed that but on the next page i did `<?php echo $_POST["first_name[0]"]` but it didn't display anything. I don't know if that's syntactically correct either. Is it right?

Comment: Not very sure but if I recall correctly it would be `$_POST["first_name"][0]`, just in case I'm wrong try `var_dump($_POST);` to see all the values inside the $_POST variable

Comment: @xcecption okay great it's posting and i am dynamically putting a newly added row into the next spot in the array. Do you know how to delete it though?

Comment: @xception nvm i figured it out xD, thanks a bunch. One last thing, if i delete the 2nd entry in an array, do you know how to consolidate it? So if it has five entries, and i delete entry #2, the entry 3-5 should move to the left by one and become entries #2-4. Any ideas

Comment: Delete the whole row instead of just the input if you have a validation error ... when you have the input go to it's parent (this will usually be .parent or .getParent()  until you hit the tr element) and delete that. could you also mark my response as correct since I solved your problem? I'm trying to build some reputation here... going very slowly so far.

Comment: @xception Yah i did all that but that's not what I was asking. So all the first names are in an array called fnames. So row 1's first name is stored in fnames[0], row 2's is in fnames[1], etc. But lets say I have 3 rows and i delete row 2, i already can delete the row and the element from the array. But the fnames array now looks like this fnames[0, NULL, 2], i want to make it fnames[0,2]

Comment: If you delete the whole row not just the fnames input it will fix the php side for you... by not submitting the nonexisting elements you will no longer get the null value in the place of the missing element, anyway you should validate from php side as well, do a check and eliminate any rows containing NULL values or invalid input, javascript can easily be disabled and a malicious user could use that against your code